# SPM plugin - how to add plugin so it doesn’t require skipPackagePluginValidation option

Tags: swift, xcode, security, command-line-interface, swift-package-manager

Right now, if You want to use SPM plugin like SwiftLint inside your package it requires passing `-skipPackagePluginValidation` option when building from command line. In Xcode there is pop up. For me it is serious security risk.

Is there any option to add plug-in and it will pass validation? What have to be done on plug-in side, and what on client side?
Will adding checksum solve the validation problem?

I have tried building via xcodebuild and via swift test commands.

Comment: How did you get to this option? I can't seem to find any documentation on it. Do you know if it is available vía gym on fastlane?

Comment: @MatiasContreras I'm not able to find docs, either, but there's [discussion here](https://forums.swift.org/t/telling-xcode-14-beta-4-to-trust-build-tool-plugins-programatically/59305). And it does look like [you can use it via gym on fastlane](https://pullanswer.com/questions/the-following-build-commands-failed-validate-plug-in-rswiftgenerateinternalresources-in-package-r-swift) with `xcargs: "-skipPackagePluginValidation" `